# Magento all links are started with /index.php/, not just with / - WHY?

Tags: magento, routes, hyperlink

Installed Magento 1.6.2.0, and noticed that the links are like

http://MYSEUPERSTORE.com/**index.php**/customer/account/

but with elder versions of Magento they were like

http://MYSEUPERSTORE.com/customer/account/

Why does **index.php/** appear in links?
Also all links routed throuh / work as well, but Mage insists on **index.php/** and includes it everywhere. How to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would guess that System > Configuration > Web > Search Engine Optimisation > Use Web Server Rewrites is set to false in your admin section. Setting it to true, then clearing your cache should solve the issue.

Comment: It's actually System > Configuration > **Web** > Search Engine Optimisation > Use Web Server Rewrites